How to calculate risk of choosing option0 vs option1
I have an expirement where every day a person has to pick between $image0$ and $image1$, where based on your selection you can win $1$, loose $1$, or $0$.
I am given the following probabilities:
$r0$: probability of winning with $image0$
$p0$: probability of loosing with $image0$
$r1$: probability of winning with $image1$
$p1$: probability of loosing with $image1$
Note that the probabilities for one image don't add up to 1, since the remainig probability is the probability of getting neutral.
Now, given the above, and the choice $0/1$ she made, I want to calculate a score of the risk she took.
My logic is that the risk of an image (independet of the choice) should be associated with having low probability of neutral. For me, the people that risk the less are those that want to stay neutral. For example the following probability: [$0.5, 0.5, 0]$ is much riskier than $[0.15, 0.15, 0.7]$ - even tho they have the same expectation.
Other people made me think that instead a higher risk is simply associated with a higher probability of loosing.
My formula, following my idea, then calculates the variance for $image0$ and $image1$. Then, to get the risk of "a choice instead of the other", I normalize. Overall this is what I do to get my risk of a choice:
def get_risk_taken(prob0: list, prob1: list, choice: int):
outcomes = [1, -1, 0]
rv0 = rv_discrete(values=(outcomes, prob0))
rv1 = rv_discrete(values=(outcomes, prob1))
var0 = rv0.var()
var1 = rv1.var()
total_variance = var0 + var1
riskiness0 = var0 / total_variance
riskiness1 = var1 / total_variance
return riskiness0 if choice == 0 else riskiness1

I'd like to get a second opinion on wether my idea and the implementation is correct, and how to consider those who say that I should look at risk as a higher probability of loosing.
